# Criar serialização com dados de duas tabelas

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Boa noite pessoal, preciso de ajuda para conseguir serializar os dados conforme "Resultado desejado" mas só estou conseguindo o resultado da imagem "Resultado que estou conseguindo", alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigado!

**Resultado que estou conseguindo**
[image: Resultado que estou conseguindo]

**Resultado desejado**

[image: Resultado desejado]

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey("Checkout", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Checkout', related_name="cart")
    item = models.ForeignKey("Product", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cartItens")
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=5, verbose_name="Quantidade")
    line_item_total = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Itens dos Checkout'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}x {}'.format(self.cart, self.quantity, self.item)


class Checkout(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="ID")
    products = models.ManyToManyField("Product", through=CartItem, related_name='tracks')
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    total_amount_with_discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    total_discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Checkout'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Pedido: {}'.format(self.id)


class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="ID")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Nome do produto")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Descrição")
    price = models.DecimalField('Preço', decimal_places=0, max_digits=8)
    is_gift = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Brinde")
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Data de criação")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
        verbose_name = 'Produto'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Produtos'
        unique_together = (('id', 'title'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Checkout, CartItem, Product


class CheckoutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Checkout
        fields = ['total_amount', 'total_amount_with_discount','total_discount', 'products']


class CartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['cart', 'item', 'quantity','line_item_total']


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'description','price', 'is_gift']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from apps.checkout.models import Checkout, CartItem, Product
from apps.checkout.serializers import CheckoutSerializer


class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)


@csrf_exempt
def checkout(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        checkout = Checkout.objects.all()
        serializer = CheckoutSerializer(checkout, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)

        total_amount = 0
        total_amount_with_discount = total_amount - 200
        total_discount = 200

        checkout = Checkout

        for item in data['products']:

            product_id = item['id']
            product_quantity = item['quantity']


            produto = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)

            unit_amount = int(produto.price)
            is_gift = produto.is_gift

            # Valor total
            amount_item = unit_amount * product_quantity

            # Soma ao valor total do pedido
            total_amount = total_amount + amount_item


            checkout.total = total_amount
            checkout.save()


        serializer = CheckoutSerializer(data=data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from apps.checkout.views import checkout


urlpatterns = [
    path('', checkout),
    #path('<str:username>', funcionario_detalhes),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aninhar serializers é mais fácil do que parece. Vou dar um exemplo geral, e você pode se aprofundar mais [nessa documentação.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Aninhar é quando você tem um modelo, que tem que ser "chamado", na serialização de outro modelo.

O serializer do modelo que deve ser "puxado" pelo outro deve ser declarado antes. Logo abaixo dele, o serializer do modelo que você quer usar como principal, deve chamar o serializer do outro modelo, e adicioná-lo aos fields. Esse exemplo vem da documentação.

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'title', 'duration']

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']
```

Many serve para receber mais de um valor, e o read_only pode ser desativado caso você crie e atualize seus modelos dentro do serializer.

Veja, o AlbumSerializer "chama" o serializer secundário, a resposta desse serializer vai ser incluída como um field normal. Como eu disse, é uma ideia geral, mas ela pode ser aplicada ao seu problema.